# Prevent field from adding to savedInstanceBundle

Tags: android, performance

Is there are any way to not include the **field** in **`saveInstanceBundle`** in **Android** when `void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` is called?

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: @tpA currently I don't have any idea how to do this. My question to get info, at least, if it's possible to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields are not added automatically. You have to write/read each one by yourself. If that's your case, just don't do anything with that field.

If there's a field which is already added (like visibility or text in TextView), you have to find it and remove it after calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()`.